# Denied croatia impact on my travel to spain

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas, spain, croatia

Hello there currently i will be visiting spain they issued  me multiple entry 90 days however i am afraid that they might turned me down at the border will it most likely to happen and will i be at the schengen information  system? Because on last years trip i was not allowed to travel to croatia  due to single entrance schengen visa  however the croatian  border  guard  did not stamp my passpored with a cancellation stamp nor asking me to sign any letter related for the purpose of refusal entry he just asked me to go back to ljubjana to apply a croatian visa or travel within the schengen area as a replacement thank you.My question is only will i face problem due to my pass of being denied entry at croatia and will i be at the sis system ? Thank you

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your commeng appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly unlikely that you will be denied entry to Spain. Mainly because you don't have any denial stamp on your passport nor is it present in the system, so technically you will be fine with your journey.

Comment: Yes hopefully i will not be at the system i that is why i asked and i have contacted some people of being denied entry to croatia with a stamp and they have to sign in a letter and still they can visit the schengen area even croatia freely.Thank your for your answering Alekhya.

Comment: No problem, you will absolutely have no problems visiting Schengen Area.